# What model to use when multiple independent variables and annual data

Tags: time-series, multiple-regression

I have multiple independent variables and my dependent variable. These are observed at an annual basis. I want to know how much the independent ones affect the dependent. What I am wondering most about is the time. Because the effect on the dependent variable is likely to be lagged, so that the Y in say year 2010 is dependent on what happened in 2009 too ...

Is it possible to incorporate lag in Y when I have multiple independent variables ...? Is this a time series problem?? Maybe I could use time as an independent variable?

What I am not sure about is what kind of model to apply to this problem ...

Edit: the Y variable is energy production in each year, and the X variables are price of energy and different policies such as kvotas and taxes for the respective years :) sample size is 10 years

Comment: This is to abstract. Could you tell us what this variables represent in real life, sample size, ... ?

Comment: Yes, so the Y variable is energy production in each year, and the X variables are price of energy and different policies such as kvotas and taxes for the respective years :) sample size is 10 years. Thanks!

Comment: Please add this information as an edit to the post, as we want posts to be self-contained, and comments are easily overseen, and can be deleted

Comment: Sure! were you able to help me now?